# SQL - reducing a query to one call instead of two

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables `order` and `multileg_order`. Order can be a part of a `multileg_order` or not. If it is a part of a `multileg_order` it will have an id of `multileg_order` in the field `multileg_id` and a type `Flight` or `Courier`. And `multileg_order` has an array of order ids, so it can be made of courier - flight - courier orders for example.
Here are the definitions of tables with relevant columns:

```
create table multileg_order
(
    id          bigserial
        primary key,
    shipment_id text                                            not null
        unique,
    order_ids   bigint[]                 default '{}'::bigint[] not null,
);


create table order
(
    id                       bigserial
        primary key,
    multileg_seq_number      integer,
    multileg_id              bigint
    type                     text,
);
```

I am making a query based on a param `order_id` where I should find out if the order is a part of `multileg_order`, if it is I should then see if any of the orders that are part of that multileg order are of a type `Flight`.
So for example if I have orders that look like this:

```
id | multileg_seq_number | multileg_id | type

1  |          0          |       1     | Courier
2  |          1          |       1     | Flight
3  |          2          |       1     | Courier
```

They are all a part of a multileg_order:

```
id |    shipment_id      |    order_ids 

1  |       1234          |    {1, 2, 3}
```

And if I make a query with an order id = 1 I want to know if it is a part of a multileg order where at least one of the orders are of type `Flight`, in this example that would be the case. I could check that with first getting the `multileg_id`:

```
select multileg_id from order where id = :id
```

But, then I need to check if any of the other orders from that multileg order are of the type `Flight`.

```
select count(*)
from order
where multileg_id = multilegId AND type = 'FLIGHT'
```

I wonder If I can do all of that in one query?

Comment: Sample data might help your question.

Comment: Sounds like you may be able to use EXISTS.

Comment: A side note on the database design: `identity` columns are recommended over the old `serial` columns. And more often than not, de-normalizing a model using arrays is a bad choice.

Answer (score 0):

This has finally served my purpose:

```
SELECT *
FROM multileg_order AS mo
       join order as o on mo.id = o.multileg_id and type = 'FLIGHT'
WHERE id = ANY(order_ids);
```